# Any reason for completing 100% of camp before conquering it?

Tags: mad-max

Is there any reason I should struggle to complete a camp 100% before conquering it?

Because sometimes it's more time saving to explore some parts of the camp after you conquered it for some of them are huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Well, not really.

Any of the collectibles/scrap will always be available to collect after the camp has been conquered. The only reason I would think that you might want to try to 100% it before actually finishing is that you *might* run into some weapons/explosives on the way that will help you take out some enemies... Other than that, there is no real benefit to struggling to get the 100% if you can just do it afterwards anyway.

Comment: I always hated having to go through that completion menu twice though, once after beating the main objective, and then a second time when i pick up that one piece of scrap or destroy that one insignia I missed.